# using v7 support library gives this error: The type android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable

Tags: android, android-support-library

I spent hours and hours on this and I can't seem to resolve it. I have my app which supports Api 8 and above. I wanted to add the support library v7 appCompat . Therefore, using the sdk manager, I downloaded the most recent support library and the most recent SDK (5.0). I imported the library with resources as per
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

However, in my project where  I extend ActionBarActivity, I keep getting the following error on the ActionBarActivity

```
The type android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I am using eclipse, What can I do?! What is it I am missing.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: no one faced this issue? Comon!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse error – The type android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

The simple solution is not to Copy-Paste the support library in the libs folder of your app but to right click on the project => Android Tools => Add Support Library

following these steps resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Do I do it after I import the support library as a project? Keep in mind I need the support library with resources

Comment: just add it by right click on the project => Android Tools => Add Support Library after you have imported.It solved it for me.Thanks

Comment: @piyush I tried with `add external jar` and adding jar in `libs` but it didn't worked. thankyou your way works for me.

Comment: facing the same issue in android studio what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project => Android Tools => Add Support Library

[Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library) is a description to add a support library

But ActionBarActivity [is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). You should use AppCompatActivity instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by also adding 'android-support-v4.jar' (Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs). It seems that 'android-support-v7-appcompat.jar' alone is not enough.